# Reading multiple square brackets value one line in Java IO

Tags: java, java-io

I have code that reading a file contains multiple square brackets [] in one line, i will take that value (inside square brackets) and will be replaced by another string. The problem is i just got first square brackets value in the line and the others cannot be handled. This is my code :

```
if (line.contains("[") && line.contains("]")) {
    getindex = getIndexContent(line);

}
```

And the method to get the index value:

```
String getIndexContent(String str) {
    int startIdx = str.indexOf("[");
    int endIdx = str.indexOf("]");

    String content = str.substring(startIdx + 1, endIdx);
    return content;
}
```

And this is the file contain square brackets that i read:

```
 var[_ii][_ee] = init_value;
```

Well, i have got the _ii value but how get the _ee that the second value of square brackets? I just imagine that store in Array, but i don't know how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it with regex like this.

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[[^\\[.]+?\\]");

        String str = "dt = (double[]) obj[i];";

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
```

You can also get the first and last indices of every matches.
matcher.start() and matcher.end() will return the starting index and the ending index of the current match.

Comment: @Samul Afifin No, It does not. It's just need to be recursive for that

Comment: Then how if line contains nested square brackets, any solution?

Comment: Change Pattern.compile("\\[.+?\\]") to Pattern.compile("\\[[^\\[.]+?\\]")

Comment: i have problem with Pattern.compile("\\[.+?\\]") as you answered above. why pattern cannot found this [i] in this line code 'dt = (double[]) obj[i];' ? What's wrong?

Comment: @Samsul Arifin I have edit my answer. Please check again.

Comment: thanks. I have edited your answer before and replacing + with *, everything fine. Would you mind, if i ask you about another topic. I have a problem with how to read a method and variable insides. I mean i read a java class that contains some method. then how i can get methods and variable inside in the class? please check this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083519/check-duplicate-variable-in-a-method-scope-java/)

Answer (score 3):

you can iterate through your `String` until you got all
also make life easy by returning all within one method:

```
List<String> getIndexContent(String str) {

 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

 while(true){
    if(!str.contains("[") && !str.contains("]")){
      break;
    }
    int startIdx = str.indexOf("[");
    int endIdx = str.indexOf("]");

    String content = str.substring(startIdx + 1, endIdx);
    list.add(content);
    if(endIdx==str.length()-1){
      break;
    }
    str=str.subString(endIdx+1,str.length());
 }

    return list;
}
```

**NOTE:**

> it won't work on nested brackets

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried this code. But it seem different data type, i mean must convert from String to list. Nice code!

Comment: @SamsulArifin well, if you want to extract all matched information then this is one way of doing it, since you may have more than one then you need to store the data in a different datatype...

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` takes an optional positional argument for the starting point of your search. If you set that to your end index, `endIdx`, plus one, it will find the second occurrence of the brackets.

```
int startIdx2 = str.indexOf("[", endIdx + 1);
int endIdx2 = str.indexOf("]", endIdx + 1);
```

Comment: Then how if there are three kind of brackets? can you please explain how read dynamically?