# Check duplicate variable in a method scope Java

Tags: java, java-io, javaparser

I read java file using `FileReader` that contains some method. How i can read method scope (method area inside) to find duplicate variable?

For example, this is a java file that i read:

```
public double[] copyArray(double[] data) {
    int _nn = data.length;
    double[] _tmp = new double[_nn];

    System.arraycopy(data, 0, _tmp, 0, _nn);
    int _nn;
    _nn = tmp;

    return _tmp;
}
```

How to know method scope?, i mean between { and }, if scope has found, find duplicate variable such as example above (int _nn) duplicated.

[addition]
i have tried using java parser, then is success. Then i should send the results using list, but only last method in the list. What's wrong with my code?

This is a MethodVisitor:

```
private static class MethodVisitor extends VoidVisitorAdapter {
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void visit(MethodDeclaration n, Object file) {
        list.add(n.getName());

    }
    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Then, this is a method to call  MethodVisitor:

```
private MethodVisitor mv;

public void doIt(File file) throws Exception {
    CompilationUnit cu;
    try {
        // parse the file
        cu = JavaParser.parse(file);
    } finally {
        //file.close();
    }
    // visit and print the methods names
    mv = new MethodVisitor();
    mv.visit(cu, file);

    List<String> list = mv.getList();

    for(String item:list){
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: use  a stack to keep track of `{` and `}`

Comment: You use a Java parser, or a compiler such as the Eclipse compiler, which will provide extensive error information and warnings (e.g. field hiding).

Comment: Compile the code. Javac won't let you declare duplicate variables.

Comment: @Ramanlfc, i am afraid if  there are more than one { inside method.

Comment: @Andreas, would you mind if you give me an example?

Comment: @AndyTurner, that's what i mean, if duplicate variable found, then remove it.

Comment: That isn't what your question asks: you ask how to *find* duplicate variables.

Comment: How would you know that simply removing it is the right solution? Why do you even have this problem? Code is either written by users and they should fix it, or it is generated by other code which shouldn't generate bad code. Trying to scan source code for something like this is the wrong approach. Kick users who left compiler errors and tell them to fix it, or fix the code generator to not generate bad code in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 you need to parse java code:

http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/

or read this:

[Java source code parsers/generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999500/java-source-code-parsers-generators)

2 after that, try something and show your code

Comment: Please use the new version of JavaParser (https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser). The one you referred to has not been updated for several years and it supports Java 1.5, while the new one is actively maintained and it supports Java 1.8

Comment: @FedericoTomassetti thanks for your reply, i have got all the method, then i want to ask you how to get all variable in each method? thanks :D